# $ \varphi $ be a homomorphism between topological groups. $\varphi$ is open if it is in the identity $ e_G $

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, solution-verification

Let $ \varphi: G \rightarrow H $ be a homomorphism between topological groups.
$ \varphi $ is open if, and only if, for every neighborhood $ U $ of $ e_G $ in $ G $, there exists $ W $ time of $ e_H $ such that $ W \subseteq \varphi (U). $

Proof:

$\Rightarrow)$ If $ \varphi $ is open, then $ \varphi (V) $ is open for all $ V $ in $ G $, given $ U $ a neighborhood of $ e_G $ then $ \varphi (U) $ is open of $ H $ since $ \varphi $ is homomorphism then $ \varphi (U) $ is a neighborhood of $ e_H $ by definition of neighborhood we have that exists $ W $ a neighborhood in $ e_H $ such that $ W \subseteq \varphi(U) $

$\Leftarrow)$  given $ V $ an open of $ G $ we must see that $ \varphi (V) $ is an open of $ H $, since $ V $ is open then $ V = gU $ for all $ g \in V $ with $ U $ a neighborhood of $ e_G $ therefore there exists $ W $ a neighborhood in $ e_H $ such that $ W \subset \varphi (U) $ so $ \varphi (g) W \subseteq \varphi (g) \varphi (U) = \varphi (gU)=\varphi(V) $ since $ W $ is open then $ \varphi (g) W $ is open, so $ \varphi (V) $ is open, therefore $ \varphi $ is open.

is my proof correct?

Comment: homeomorphism or homomorphism? $W$ time of $e_H$?

Comment: Yes, homomorphism

Comment: Then you should correct the title. What about $W$ time $e_H$ in the first sentence?